# Не работает установщик OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Скачал OpenCart, проверил все требования. Запускаю установщик, а у меня голый html-текст.

https://i.gyazo.com/4211566fd7ed40771c527629f67f1111.png (картинка большая, не стал вставлять)

Comment: А кнопочка "Continue" внизу не нажимается?

Answer (score 1):

если при установке не применились стили, то проверьте права доступа к файлам и папкам, должны быть 644(файлы) и 755(папки)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не до конца скопировали, либо архив не верно загрузился.
Перекачайте архив, распакуйте заново, и запустите установщик.